Trying to incorporate onnx model to Android App
I have a trained onnx model that I want to incorporate into an android app.After a long research, I came to the conclusion that  converting my onnx model into a TF model and then generate a TFLite model through TFLite Converter API, or give it a try with.
    import onnx
    from onnx_tf.backend import prepare
    onnx_model = onnx.load("/content/test_128.onnx")  
    tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)  # prepare tf representation
    tf_rep.export_graph("/content/output.pb") # <------ python crashes

  warnings.warn(
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-19aee597afda> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 onnx_model = onnx.load("/content/test_128.onnx")
      6 tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)  # prepare tf representation
----> 7 tf_rep.export_graph("/content/")

39 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/pad.py in process_neg_pads(x, paddings, constant_values)
     38                         ends = ag__.ld(i_shape) + ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).gather, (ag__.ld(paddings), ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).range, (ag__.ld(i_rank), ag__.ld(i_rank) * 2), None, fscope_2)), None, fscope_2)
     39                         sizes = ag__.ld(ends) - ag__.ld(begins)
---> 40                         result = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).slice, (ag__.ld(x), ag__.ld(begins), ag__.ld(sizes)), None, fscope_2)
     41                         try:
     42                             do_return_2 = True

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend_tf_module.py", line 99, in __call__  *
        output_ops = self.backend._onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op(onnx_node,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/backend.py", line 347, in _onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op  *
        return handler.handle(node, tensor_dict=tensor_dict, strict=strict)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/handler.py", line 59, in handle  *
        return ver_handle(node, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/pad.py", line 91, in version_11  *
        return cls._common(node, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/onnx_tf/handlers/backend/pad.py", line 35, in process_neg_pads  *
        result=tf.slice(x, begins, sizes)

    ValueError: Invalid value in tensor used for shape: -3


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

hi @ sachindu , The error you are facing during the conversion from ONNX to tensorflow. First think make sure you are using the latest version of one-tf package,Try saving the model in TensorFlow using the prepare function from onnx-tf ,if still you are facing the same issue then share your entire code.
